# Trying to use spring MVC validator with parent child class relation.Getting an error more details below

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, validation, stack-trace, pojo

I am actually trying to validate a form named user.jsp which .the "Class User" .. has a reference of "class inuser"(this class has only one attribute qualification)which is another class. when i keep the qualification field "" blank the system gives a stack trace which i have pasted below. Please help if possible i will be thankfull.

```
package net.roseindia.web;

public class User {

   public User(){
      iu=new inuser();
   }


private String name;    
private String emailid;
private String dob;
private String address;
private inuser iu;
private String contact;


public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}
public String getEmailid() {
    return emailid;
}

public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
    this.emailid = emailid;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
    public void setIu(inuser iu) {
         this.iu = iu;
    }
    public inuser getIu() {
         return iu;
    }
}
```

then my inuser class:

```
 public class inuser {
 public inuser() {} 
 private String qualification;

 public void setQualification(String qualification) {
this.qualification = qualification;
 }

public String getQualification() {
return qualification;
}
}
```

this is how my form is partly:

```
 <tr>
 <td>Qualification:</td>
 <td><form:input path="iu.qualification"/></td>
 <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="iu.qualification"/></font></td>
 </tr>
```

validation class :

```
import java.util.regex.*;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import net.roseindia.web.User;

public class UserValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return User.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
    User user = (User) obj;     

    if ((user.getEmailid() != "") || (user.getEmailid().length()) != 0)       

    {           
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
        Matcher m=p.matcher(user.getEmailid());
        boolean b=m.matches();
        if(b!=true)
        {
   errors.rejectValue("emailid", "error.is.not.valid", "Email ID does not   
   Valid");         
        }
    }

    if ((user.getContact() != "") || (user.getContact().length()) != 0) 

   {            
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1}-\\d{4}-\\d{6}");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(user.getContact());
            boolean con=matcher.matches();
            if(con!=true)
                {
                    errors.rejectValue("contact",   
     "error.is.not.valid", "Enter Contact Number Like 0-9999-999999");
                }
    }
    if ((user.getDob() != "") || (user.getDob().length()) != 0) {           
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(user.getDob());
        boolean DOB=matcher.matches();
        if(DOB!=true)
            {
                errors.rejectValue("dob", "error.is.not.valid", 
   "Enter Date of birth Like 01/02/1986 ");
            }
    }
    if (user.getName() == null || user.getName().length() == 0) {
        errors.rejectValue("name", "error.empty.field", "Please Enter Name");
    }        
    if (user.getDob() == null || user.getDob().length() == 0) {
        errors.rejectValue("dob", "error.empty.field", "Please Enter Date Of Birth");
    }        
    if (user.getContact() == null || user.getContact().length() == 0) {
        errors.rejectValue("contact", "error.empty.field", "Please Enter Contact 
    Number");
    }        
    if (user.getEmailid() == null || user.getEmailid().length() == 0) {
        errors.rejectValue("emailid", "error.empty.field", "Please Enter Email ID");
    }
    //====>>>here===>>      if (user.getIu().getQualification()=="" ) {
        errors.rejectValue("qualification", "error.empty.field", "Please Enter   
    Qualification");
    }
    if (user.getAddress() == null || user.getAddress().length() == 0) {
        errors.rejectValue("address", "error.empty.field", "Please Enter Address");
    }
    }
    }
```

myu statck trace when i leave qualification field blank (i.e) the    field from the inuser class

```
        org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:    
        Invalid property 'qualification' of bean class [net.roseindia.web.User]: Bean  
        property 'qualification' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does 
        the  return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'qualification' of bean class [net.roseindia.web.User]: Bean property 'qualification' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:540)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:532)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:79)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.rejectValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:102)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractErrors.rejectValue(AbstractErrors.java:122)
    org.springframework.validation.BindException.rejectValue(BindException.java:126)
    net.roseindia.web.UserValidator.validate(UserValidator.java:59)
    org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(ValidationUtils.java:63)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.BaseCommandController.bindAndValidate(BaseCommandController.java:395)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`if (user.getIu().getQualification()=="" )`

try

`if (user.getIu().getQualification() == null ||  user.getIu().getQualification().isEmpty())`

Answer (score 0):

i think you used like
errors.rejectValue("qualification", "error.empty.field", "Please Enter
Qualification");

What spring tries to match is "qualification" in User object but there is nothing like that as qualification is under "inuser" object. Also your form mapping is like

you need to reject the value like "iu.qualification". Try doing that.